# WPF Multi-TextBoxes User Control

Tags: wpf, user-controls

I want to have a user control[say UC1] comprising 4 text boxes [say tb1,tb2,tb3, and tb4]. This user control should have 4 normal properties [say prop1, prop2, prop3, and prop4] binding to these text boxes. I want a dependency property [say dp] exposed to outer world by this user control. 
This user control gets a single string [say 0\abc|1\def|2\ghi|3\jkl] from a property[say StrProp] of class [say C1] and is splitted into 4 parts[say abc, def, ghi, and jkl] to display in 4 text boxes of my user control. If any changes done by user in any or all textboxes, all the changed texts should be combined and reflected back to class C1\StrProp property.
Also, my requirement is that dp should be bounded to StrProp in UI\XAML. Validations should also be done properly.

Can anyone please help me by writing an example?
Sample classes are as below:

MyMultiTextBoxUserControl.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyMultiTextBoxControl_UsingNConsuming.MyMultiTextBoxUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height=".25*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height=".25*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height=".25*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height=".25*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding ElementName=UserControl, Path=CombinedField1 }"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding ElementName=UserControl, Path=CombinedField2}"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding ElementName=UserControl, Path=CombinedField3}"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="3" Text="{Binding ElementName=UserControl, Path=CombinedField4}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

MyMultiTextBoxUserControl.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MyMultiTextBoxUserControl : UserControl
    {
        public MyMultiTextBoxUserControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        //static FrameworkPropertyMetadata propertydata = new FrameworkPropertyMetadata("Hello",
        //    FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, new PropertyChangedCallback(PropertyChanged_Callback), new CoerceValueCallback(CoerceValue_Callback),
        //    false, UpdateSourceTrigger.LostFocus);

        //public static readonly DependencyProperty CombinedTextProperty =
        //    DependencyProperty.Register("CombinedText", typeof(string), typeof(MyMultiTextBoxUserControl), propertydata, new ValidateValueCallback(Validate_ValueCallback));


        static FrameworkPropertyMetadata propertydata = new FrameworkPropertyMetadata("Hello",
           FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, new PropertyChangedCallback(PropertyChanged_Callback));
        public static readonly DependencyProperty CombinedTextProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("CombinedText", typeof(string), typeof(MyMultiTextBoxUserControl), propertydata);


        private static bool Validate_ValueCallback(object value)
        {
            string str=value as string;
            bool result = true;
            if (str.Length > 28)
                result = false;
            if (str.Length < 1)
                result = false;
            if (str.Substring(0, 2) != "0'\'")
                result = false;
            if (str.Contains("1'\'") == false || str.Contains("2'\'") || str.Contains("3'\'"))
                result = false;
            return result;
        }

        private static object CoerceValue_Callback(DependencyObject obj,object value)
        {
            return value;
        }

        private static void PropertyChanged_Callback(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {            
            MyMultiTextBoxUserControl control=(MyMultiTextBoxUserControl)obj;
            string select = e.NewValue.ToString();
            char[] pipeDelim,slashDelim;
            string[] pipeSplt;
            pipeDelim = new char[] { '|' };
            slashDelim = new Char[] { '/' };
            pipeSplt = select.Split(pipeDelim);
            if (pipeSplt.Length == 1)
                return;
            string[][] str = new string[4][];
            int x = 0;
            foreach (string s in pipeSplt)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s) == false)
                {
                    str[x] = s.Split(slashDelim);
                    x++;
                }
            }
            control.CombinedField1 = str[0][1];
            control.CombinedField2 = str[1][1];
            control.CombinedField3 = str[2][1];
            control.CombinedField4 = str[3][1];
        }

        public string CombinedText
        {
            get { return GetValue(CombinedTextProperty) as string; }
            set { SetValue(CombinedTextProperty, value); }
        }

        public string CombinedField1 
        {
            get;  set; 
        }

        public string CombinedField2
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string CombinedField3
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string CombinedField4
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
```

CombinedStringClass.cs

```
namespace MyMultiTextBoxControl_UsingNConsuming
{
    public class CombinedStringClass
    {
        public CombinedStringClass() { }
        string m_CombinedString;
        public string CombinedString
        {
            get { return m_CombinedString; }
            set
            {
                if (m_CombinedString != value)
                    m_CombinedString = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ConsumerClass.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="MyMultiTextBoxControl_UsingNConsuming.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyMultiTextBoxControl_UsingNConsuming;assembly="        
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:CombinedStringClass x:Key="myClass"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>        
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="0.33*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="0.34*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="0.33*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Text="User Control Text Boxes" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Foreground="Black" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        <local:MyMultiTextBoxUserControl Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Foreground="Black" CombinedText="{Binding Source=myClass, Path=CombinedString, Mode=TwoWay,FallbackValue=DataNotBound}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Combied String" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Foreground="Black" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        <TextBox Name="OneStringTextBox" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Foreground="Black" Text="0\abc|1\def|2\ghi|3\jkl" IsEnabled="False"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I also need to combine the changed texts ofUserControl's textboxes in such a way that it should be in a form of [0\f|1\gh|2\zx|3\oo] to be reflected in OneStringTextBox. Also, total string length should be 28 & max length of each textbox is 7.

Answer (score 0):

Read `WPF in C# 2010: Windows Presentation Foundation in .NET 4 Matthew MacDonald` Chapter 18.
There is a great example that shoud help you.

Give name to your User control, replace {Binding ElementName=UserControl... with {Binding ElementName=NameOfUserControl, convert CombinedFields properties to DPs.

Comment: I have tried to write a small application to re-instate my problem. I am new to DependencyProperty, so might have done silly mistakes. I have edited my question with sample classes that I created. Please have a look and help me.